# ODBC Connection using R

Tags: r, odbc, rodbc

Following is the piece of code and somehow it fails. Not sure of the reasons. What could be the reasons?

```
dbhandle_dev = odbcDriverConnect('driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};server="DevSQL01";database="risk";trusted_connection=true')
```

Error message is as follows.
[RODBC] ERROR: state 08001, code 0, message [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid value specified for connection string attribute 'trusted_connection'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the one needed to solve the issue.

```
dbhandle_dev = odbcDriverConnect('driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};server="DevSQL01";database="risk";trusted_connection=Yes')
```